How can I fix overlapping axes and graphs in d3-contour?
I'm drawing a graph using contour from the d3 library, and I'm having trouble with the graph and the axes overlapping. I don't know what the problem is. The code below is the code that's causing the problem. Please help me.
function daysChart() {
    const data = {width:87, height:61, values:[102, 103, ...]}

    const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 40, left: 50 };
    const fullWidth = 960;
    const fullHeight = 500;
    const contourWidth = fullWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
    const contourHeight = fullHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    const n = data.width;
    const m = data.height;
    const scaleRatio = 0.8;
    const path = d3.geoPath().projection(d3.geoIdentity().scale(contourWidth / n));
    const contours = d3.contours().size([n, m]);
    const color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateTurbo).domain(d3.extent(data.values)).nice();
    
    const startDateStr = "2023-08-13";
    const dates = generateDateArray(startDateStr, n); 
    const x = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain(d3.extent(dates))
        .range([0, contourWidth]);

    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent([1, m]))
        .range([contourHeight, 0]);

    // full plot
    const svg = d3.select("#smps-chart")
        .attr("style", "display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", fullWidth)
        .attr("height", fullHeight)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // contour
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("Stroke", "black")
        .selectAll()
        .data(color.ticks(20))
        .join("path")
        .attr("d", d => path(contours.contour(data.values, d)))
        .attr("fill", color);

    // x axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + contourHeight + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // y axis
    svg.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
}


I tried adjusting the size of each element or moving the position using margin/padding, but it was not a meaningful attempt because the graph was cut off.

The y-axis is the expected behavior, right?
